# IllegalAccessException with grails timeZoneSelect tag on google app engine/java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, grails, timezone

Has anyone used the grails timeZoneSelect tag on GAE/J ? I've come across the error below on app engine. I know reflection is not allowed, but the line in error seems to be calling a straightforward public function (inDaylightTime)? Does anyone know how to workaround this (short of a hardcoded list of time zones)?

thanks

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag : java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on public boolean sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.inDaylightTime(java.util.Date)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:235)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5235)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5233)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:363)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$2.run(Server.java:838)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanRunnable.run(LocalTraceSpanRunnable.java:56)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanBuilder.internalContinueSpan(LocalTraceSpanBuilder.java:536)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.startRpc(Server.java:793)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.processRequest(Server.java:368)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.ServerConnection.messageReceived(ServerConnection.java:448)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.parseMessages(RpcConnection.java:319)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.dataReceived(RpcConnection.java:290)
    at com.google.net.async.Connection.handleReadEvent(Connection.java:466)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.processNetworkEvents(EventDispatcher.java:759)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.internalLoop(EventDispatcher.java:205)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:101)
    at com.google.net.rpc.RpcService.runUntilServerShutdown(RpcService.java:251)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RpcRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:394)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag : java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on public boolean sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.inDaylightTime(java.util.Date)
```

Comment: For the time being i have worked around this using a hardcoded list of the timezones. the grails timezone tag was iterating through all the time zones each time and that was causing the execution time to exceed the limit, so had to anyway optimize the page.

Comment: you may want to report this to Grails and/or GAE. Maybe they will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I tried to call TimeZone.getTimeZone() to get a TimeZone and worked around this one by using a different library, Joda Time.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html

There are equivalent time/date methods in this package that work better than those in the underlying JDK.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to dynamic languages which use reflection to invoke methods on the sun.* objects returned by java.util.TimeZone factory methods; I worked around a similar limitation in the TimeZone stuff by writing a wrapper method in Java and then calling that method, so that the invocations on the sun.* objects wouldn't be via reflection.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this technique?

Answer (score 1):

the below works for me

```
public Date getDateWithTimeZone(Date date, String timeZone){
    def tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
    def cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTimeInMillis( date.getTime() )
    cal.setTimeZone( tz )
    def offset = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)
    date.setTime( date.getTime()+offset )
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Java half of what I did:

```
package inonit.google.appengine.runtime;

import java.util.*;

public class Methods {
    public int getTimezoneOffset(String timezone, long time) {
        return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone).getOffset(time);
    }
}
```

My application isn't Grails, and I don't know enough about Grails to know whether the abstractions defined by Grails would make it easy to call into a class like this one or not.  But in my app I just went on to instantiate a local helper copy of this object and call into it when I needed to calculate timezone offsets.